# Join values from multiple nodes in XML - using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

This is a test XML not original XML. I am required to pull those blog sites only for which blogger ID exists in bloggrs block. **Is it possible using XSLT only?** I think it is not.

```
<root>
<bloggers>
<name bloggerId = "1">Jacob Sebastian</name>
<name bloggerId = "2">Adam Machanic</name>
<name bloggerId = "3">Pinal Dave</name>
<name bloggerId = "4">Steve Jones</name>
<name bloggerId = "5">Michael Coles</name>
</bloggers>
<blogs>
<url bloggerId = "1">http://www.sqlblog.com/adam_machanic </url>
<url bloggerId = "2">http://www.sqlauthority.com </url>
<url bloggerId = "3">http://www.beyondrelational.com </url>
<url bloggerId = "4">http://www.sqlblog.com/michael_coles </url>
<url bloggerId = "5">http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones </url>
<url bloggerId = "6">http://www.cnn.com/belief </url>
<url bloggerId = "7">http://www.yahoo.com/360 </url>
</blogs>
</root>
```

My output is in this form

```
+-------+----------+
| Site  | Blogger  |
+-------+----------+
| site1 | blogger1 |
| site2 | blogger2 |
+-------+----------+
```

This list will exclude site 6 and 7 because those bloggers number do not exist in bloggers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//url" />
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="url">
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="@bloggerId" />

        <xsl:if test="count(//bloggers//name[@bloggerId = $id]) &gt; 0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="//bloggers//name[@bloggerId = $id]" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for answer this question. I believe all are correct answer. Before asking I was sure it was not possible but I asked anyway :) Glad I asked.

Answer (score 3):

Even xpath is enough: `//blogs/url[@bloggerId = //bloggers/@bloggerId]`

Answer (score 2):

**This short and simple (no `xsl:variable`, no `xsl:if`) transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <table border="1">
   <thead>
     <th>Site</th><th>Blogger</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "url[@bloggerId = /*/bloggers/name/@bloggerId]">
   <tr>
     <td><a href="{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select=
     "/*/bloggers/name[@bloggerId = current()/@bloggerId]"/></td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <bloggers>
        <name bloggerId = "1">Jacob Sebastian</name>
        <name bloggerId = "2">Adam Machanic</name>
        <name bloggerId = "3">Pinal Dave</name>
        <name bloggerId = "4">Steve Jones</name>
        <name bloggerId = "5">Michael Coles</name>
    </bloggers>
    <blogs>
        <url bloggerId = "1">http://www.sqlblog.com/adam_machanic</url>
        <url bloggerId = "2">http://www.sqlauthority.com</url>
        <url bloggerId = "3">http://www.beyondrelational.com</url>
        <url bloggerId = "4">http://www.sqlblog.com/michael_coles</url>
        <url bloggerId = "5">http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones</url>
        <url bloggerId = "6">http://www.cnn.com/belief</url>
        <url bloggerId = "7">http://www.yahoo.com/360</url>
    </blogs>
</root>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<table border="1">
   <thead>
      <th>Site</th>
      <th>Blogger</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://www.sqlblog.com/adam_machanic">http://www.sqlblog.com/adam_machanic</a>
         </td>
         <td>Jacob Sebastian</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://www.sqlauthority.com">http://www.sqlauthority.com</a>
         </td>
         <td>Adam Machanic</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://www.beyondrelational.com">http://www.beyondrelational.com</a>
         </td>
         <td>Pinal Dave</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://www.sqlblog.com/michael_coles">http://www.sqlblog.com/michael_coles</a>
         </td>
         <td>Steve Jones</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <a href="http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones">http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones</a>
         </td>
         <td>Michael Coles</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```