# How to transform XML in Apache Nifi

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, apache-nifi, xslt-grouping

In NiFi I have a processor ExecuteSQL which returns the following

```
person_id| name | adress 
01       | John | Street 01 
01       | John | Street 02
02       | Deby | Street 01
```

Notice that Adress is a different table than Person, so a Left Join ends up duplicating values.

In Nifi I have converted the AVro to Json and then to XML, and this is the result:

```
<person>
  <person_id>01</person_id>
  <name>John</name>
  <address>Street 01</address>
</person>
<person>
  <person_id>01</person_id>
  <name>John</name>
  <address>Street 02</address>
</person>
<person>
  <person_id>02</person_id>
  <name>Deby</name>
  <address>Street 01</address>
</person>
```

However my desired result would be:

```
<person>
  <person_id>01</person_id>
  <name>John</name>
  <addresses>
    <address>Street 01</address>
    <address>Street 02</address>
  </addresses>
</person>
<person>
  <person_id>02</person_id>
  <name>Deby</name>
  <addresses>
    <address>Street 01</address>
  </addresses>
</person>
```

Is it possible to do it in Nifi? I can't seem to find any suitable processor for this, should I use  XSLT (with Transform XML processor) ? write my own processor? How can I do that?

I'm new to NiFi and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches you could take:

1. **Do the transformation in JSON before converting to XML** -- the [`JoltTransformJSON`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.JoltTransformJSON/index.html) processor handles complex transformations and has more documentation around that process (as well as [online sandboxes for testing](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception))
2. **Do the transformation in XSLT** -- if you're more comfortable with XSLT, you can do this with [`TransformXML`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html). There are [many Stack Overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892013/join-values-from-multiple-nodes-in-xml-using-xslt) which will help you craft the XSLT
3. **Write a Groovy script** -- If the transformation logic is difficult to craft in Jolt or XSLT, a Groovy script in [`ExecuteScript`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) will probably be the simplest solution. Groovy's XML handling is very terse and allows for powerful manipulation with map/object duck-typing. This would be my recommendation if the Jolt or XSLT specs are non-trivial
4. **Write a custom processor** -- If you build a script that works well, you can migrate that code to a custom processor for long-term benefits (performance improvements, deployability, version control, configurability, etc.). I have [recent slides](https://github.com/alopresto/slides/tree/master/dws_barcelona_2019) on the process around developing a custom processor

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have seen your slides regarding custom processor, and I have a question, can I add external libs (like a Jolt lib/jar) in the custom processor project?

Comment: Yes. Just declare it as a Maven dependency in the custom processor bundle `pom.xml` as you would for any other project.

Comment: There's also the option of using `JoltTransformRecord` on the XML